# Vim mksession not saving split windows

Tags: vim

I'm trying to save a Vim session that contains 2 panels in a vertically split layout.

I have tried using mksession and also the vim-session plugin, but whenever I reload a session, the split window is gone and I just get the panel that was selected when I saved the session. I have seen videos of other people doing the exact same process, and their split window configuration reappears.

How can I get the session to save and reload with my split window layout?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [question and answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642611/how-to-save-a-session-in-vim)

To save your session including the buffers that were open at the time use this command `:mksession ~/mysession.vim`.

To restore/reload your session use `:source ~/mysession.vim` if vim is already open, this will restore the window splits and files.

To restore/reload your session if vim is not open, open vim and restore your session using this command from the terminal `$ vim -S ~/mysession.vim`.

Comment: This did the trick!  The part that I was missing (which I could not seem to find anywhere else) is that vim has to be already open in order for the window splits to load from the saved session. I was running vim -S to start vim with a session, which did not load the splits.

Comment: Is there some reason why vim can't restore windows when invoking session from the commandline?